# Is procedural code ever appropriate for rendering a UI View?

Tags: asp.net, design-patterns, uiview

## Background

At work, I ran into some code that used a series of procedural methods to build an HTML View. It felt really wrong to me, and while working on it, I managed to introduce unintended layout changes.

See the pseudo-code below for a more detailed explanation.

## Questions

- The project was an ASP.NET web application targeting the 4.0 framework. With all the tools available to an ASP.NET developer, is there any reason this pattern would be appropriate.
- Ultimately, given no other time priorities, should this code be refactored ? It definitely smells of code fragility.

### Caveats

I'm not 100% sure if this is an appropriate question for SO. It falls in the somewhat subjective topic of programming patterns. As a subjective topic, there is the potential for the SO Answers to devolve into a discussion, which as we all know, is not the purpose of SO. I don't think this question qualifies as code-golf.

What I'm looking for is objective evidence that this particular pattern is
either a bad idea for some reason such as it leads to unmaintainable code. Or evidence that this pattern is appropriate for certain situations, bonus points for citing a specific example.

Had I written this code, I would have probably used some sort of well-known templating engine. I'd handle the logic decisions (highlight rows for people who have birthdays) in non-view code. I suppose I'm a proponent of logic-less template engines.

I apologize for the long code, I tried to keep it terse without sacrificing context. Hopefully, this will be a fun question to answer for some battle-scarred SO veteran.

## The Code

#### About the pseudo-code

The code in this question does not represent any actual programming language.
It is mostly based on JavaScript with HTML terms thrown in there. It should
be easy enough to interpret without significant mental gymnastics.

#### page load event handler

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) {

    var data = DataLayer.getData();
    var engine = new DataViewRenderEngine(data);
    var divElement = engine.Render();

    document.body.add(divElement);

}
```

#### Definition of DataViewRenderEngine

```
class DataViewRenderEngine {

    private _dataSource = null;

    public DataViewRenderEngine(dataSource) {
        this._dataSource = dataSource;
    }

    public Element Render() {
        return RenderView(this._dataSource);
    }

    private Element RenderView(data) {

        var containerDiv = RenderContainerDiv(data);            

        var pageHeader = PenderPageHeader(data.Title);
        containerDiv.add(pageHeader)    

        var personTable = renderPersonTable(data.PeopleArray)
        containerDiv.add(personTable);

        return containerDiv;        

    }

    private Element RenderContainerDiv() {
        return new Element({
            tag: 'div',
            class: 'container'
        });
    }

    private Element RenderPageHeader(title) {       
        return new Element({
            tag: 'h1',
            innerHTML: title        
        });     
    }

    private Element RenderPersonTable(peopleArray) {

        var table = new Element('table');

        for(var person in peopleArray) {
            var row = RenderPersonTableRow(person);
            table.add(row); 
        }

        return table;
    }

    private Element RenderTableRow(person) {
        var row = new Element('tr');

        row.add(new Element({
            tag: 'td',
            innerHTML: person.firstName     
        });

        row.add(new Element({
            tag: 'td',
            innerHTML: person.lastName      
        });

        var today = Date.Today();
        if(person.birthday.Month == today.Month &&
           person.birthday.Day   == today.Day) {
            row.BackgroundColor = 'green';
        }

        return row; 
    }

}
```

Comment: I'm also not sure it belongs here. Maybe the Software Engineering site? I haven't read their policy on "best practices" questions in a while though. The refactoring / code fragility questions seem like they might be on topic there. But again, I haven't read their policies in a while.

Comment: To whoever voted to close the question for being opinion-based: I tried to address that concern in the body of my question, so can you please comment as to why you think there is no objective answer to this question. Unless the vote was from  @Tophandour , then thank you for the feedback.

Comment: the vote wasn't from me, but I imagine whoever it is might have similar thoughts. Personally I'm just not sure where this belongs and I'm deferring to someone who knows the other pages' policies better.

Answer (score 1):

Actually it seems like you think that *object-oriented programming* has no trace of the past: procedural programming is still there.

When you implement methods, their bodies are still procedural. That is, you're calling *methods* which used to be procedures and functions later fused into a single concept.

Later on, there're good and bad designs. If your coworker's code looks like your pseucode, then it seems that it *smells*.

A *render engine* shouldn't be tied to a particular *view*. Yours seem like a mix of a *view*, *view template* and *view renderer*. Thus, clearly breaks *single responsibility principle* as it does too many things.

Conclusion: it's just a bad design/architecture. That's all.

Now I'll answer your concrete questions:

> The project was an ASP.NET web application targeting the 4.0
>   framework. With all the tools available to an ASP.NET developer, is
>   there any reason this pattern would be appropriate.

In 2017, probably you shouldn't invest more effort on ASP.NET Web Forms. If they did this way, either adapt yourself to their bad design, or convince them to switch to ASP.NET MVC or even to abandon server-side view programming in favor of a full HTML5 web app on the client-side.

> Ultimately, given no other time priorities, should this code be
>   refactored ? It definitely smells of code fragility.

This question deserves the same answer as your first one.